# Apache refuses connection from other computers

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, port, httpd

It's been two days that I try everything I think to solve my problem, but there I really do not see where it comes from.

On a Centos 7 server I configured Apache to listen on ports 80 and 5555. It works properly locally, but the connection is refused from any other machine on the network (the ping works correctly).

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:5555
```

The folder is configured to accept all connections:

```
Require all granted
```

I added the ports in SELinux and in firewalld. I even tried setenforce 0 and disable the firewall, but still the same.

In fact, the connection is refused with port 5555 while on port 80 an authentication window appears, but I do not know where it comes from.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      300/httpd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      300/httpd
```

Comment: If you see behavior you don’t expect from the server’s Apache instance (the logon window you described); could you have configured the server with an IP address that’s already in use in your network?

Comment: Thank you! You were right: a device not in the IP plan seems to have that static IP. I changed the address of that server and now I have to find the ù$*£ing device! But it works! ^^